# Get User location and show it on map(map that isn't appearing for me)

Tags: android, openstreetmap

I'm doing a university project, and i've to show user location in the OSM map, and markers with data from Retrofit API. 
I'm not worried about api data right now, but with my map that isn't showing.

All i got is this:[MainMap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/px5sa.png)
The coordinates here are random.

My map activity:

```java
    public class MapaPrincipal extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
    private MapView osm;
    private MapController mc;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapa_principal);

        osm = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        osm.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
        osm.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        osm.setMultiTouchControls(true);

        mc = (MapController) osm.getController();

        GeoPoint center = new GeoPoint(14.1, 19.2);

        mc.setZoom(12);
        mc.animateTo(center);

        addMarker(center);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    Activity#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void addMarker(GeoPoint center){
        Marker marker = new Marker(osm);
        marker.setPosition(center);
        marker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);


        osm.getOverlays().clear();
        osm.getOverlays().add(marker);
        osm.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        GeoPoint center = new GeoPoint(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

        mc.animateTo(center);
        addMarker(center);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(locationManager!=null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        }
    }
}
```

My map layout:

```java
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Android Manifest:

```java
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pt.ipp.estg.osm">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SignUpActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MapaPrincipal" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Are any errors showing in the console?

Comment: No buddy. The app runs normally